# How can I encrypt a file with dm-crypt?

Tags: arch-linux, security, encryption, dm-crypt

I've never encrypted files in my Linux distribution. Now I need to do that. I'm on Arch. I went to the documentation, it says that support of TrueCrypt is discontinued and after examining other libraries there I decided to use dm-crypt. But I can't figure out how to simply encrypt a file with it. It requires creating a partition or  something like a container. I don't need that.

How can I encrypt a file with dm-crypt?

Comment: Please provide a link for "the documentation" you went to recommending dm-crypt for file level encryption is about as appropriate as if the text would have recommended starting to draw a pentagram on the floor...

Comment: @Anthon, who told you that?

Comment: You did. **You** wrote you went to the documentation. It is in the fourth sentence of your post.

Comment: @Anthon, I didn't. You're dreaming. Re-read it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) is a  transparent disk encryption subsystem. That being said, it's better suited to encrypt disks and partitions. It can encrypt files, but they have to be mapped as devices for this to work.

If you want to encrypt only one file, GnuPG could be a better tool. Example:

```
gpg -c filename
```

**See Also:**

- [nixCraft: Linux: HowTo Encrypt And Decrypt Files With A Password](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html)
- [7 Tools to Encrypt/Decrypt and Password Protect Files in Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-password-protect-files-with-encryption/)

Comment: is that how people encrypt files before they upload them to dropbox?

Comment: @OskarK. No `dm-crypt` is **not** how people encrypt files before uploading anywhere

Comment: This can be a subject of another question. If you encrypt file by file and submit to your sync provider, will be a pain in the a**. If you use dm-crypt for your home partition, it will be mounted and your sync provider will see the last layer of transparent encryption, thus, will be send as the file is. If you use something like truecrypt and create one big encrypted file(mounted as a folder) and sync it, every bit of change will require the upload of the full file(unless your sync solution is viewing the files through the folder where it's mounted).

Comment: Also, take a look at this. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/encrypt-dropbox-data-encfs-linux/  - EncFS should be the way to do local folder encryption and submit data to Dropbox.

Comment: @Anthon: I don't see what would be the problem in encrypting a container (with 100 files in it) with dm-crypt and uploading it, instead of 100 smallish files.

Comment: @QuoraFeans The problem should be clear: you would need to get a hold of 99 smallish files if you only have one that you want to encrypt to start with ("how can I encrypt a file ...").

Comment: @Anthon: he also says: "never encrypted files (...) Now I need to do that." Or whatever. Anyway, I am not surprised the question was closed.

Answer (score 1):

`dm-crypt` only works with block devices, not files. You can still encrypt files by using loop devices, `cryptsetup` will even automatically create those loop devices as needed.

However, this is only suitable for special cases, for example in an Initramfs where `cryptsetup` is the encryption tool you already have and you don't want the bloat of adding another. This particular example is described here:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Encrypted_keyfile

Using this method the encrypted "file" will always be of a size multiple of 512 bytes - since it's a block device based on sectors; there is no metadata to support arbitrary file sizes of odd bytes. For those you'd need a container filesystem, or wrap it using `tar`, `gzip`, or similar.

So while special solutions are available and you could do it if you really really wanted to, it's just not meant for file encryption.